# Hidden Packages in Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, package, adb, samsung-mobile-sdk

1. I'm using **Samsung Galaxy S5** with **Android 5.0**. I'm trying to uninstall one of my apps via **ADB (Android Debug Bridge)**. Unfortunately, although I see the application in the application manager, I can't find the package using the **Device Storage**.
2. I was also trying to **find the package** via the following process:

   - Running **CMD**
   - **Adb shell ls -R > test.txt**
   - Searching for the **PACKAGE NAME** in the TXT file.
3. After Conducting the above process, I noticed that **I can see only some of the packages** which installed on my device.
4. Does someone have an idea on **how to find the "Hidden" Packages**?

Cheers,

Daniel

Comment: you can use this command to get all the packages " adb shell pm list packages "..

Comment: I wonder why there is no `-h` filter. There is `-d` to list *disabled* pacakges.